# Orchestra parser signature

Tags: xml-parsing, laravel-5.7, orchestra

I need to update some xml persers which uses Orchestra/parser for Laravel. So I need to find out how it works. On package page there is no documentation. If you have some give the link please. Cause there are signatures like

```
    $dataPrinters = $xml->parse([
        'printer' => ['uses' => 'printer[id,title,small_img,large_img]']
    ]);
```

Can somebody tell me please what means this signature? What exactly means that array literal in string. It looks weird. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

So I have it. The signature `'printer' => ['uses' => 'printer[id,title,small_img,large_img]']` means that if the xml looks like

```
<root>
    <printer>
        <id>1</id><title>xxxx</title>...
    </printer>
    <printer>
        <id>2</id><title>yyyyyy</title>...
    </printer>
</root>
```

it create the array like

```
[
    printer => [
        ['id' => 1, 'title' => 'xxxx' ...], 
        ['id' => 2, 'title' => 'yyyyyy' ....]
    ]
]
```